# how to add joomla module/plugin/extension into my custom php code

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have created a php website and now I want to add a directory module into my website. In joomla there is already joomla 2.5 mosets tree directory extension available. So can I add this extension into my website? If yes, then how can I do this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use Joomla? Make it match the other website visually if you want that for some reason.

Comment: @Elin actually i already hv an website, and now  i want to add directory into my website and  want to save my time to create module like "mosets tree directory extension" that's why i am looking for an idea thorough which i can integrate that joomla plugin into my Core PHP website